# What word could I be hearing here?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, pronunciación

I've been listening to some Spanish audio files which, at the end of each chapter, go back over the chapter in a form of summary. The reader always says something that sounds like, "Vijemonos" (Bvee HAY muh nos).

It could be something like "let's see" based on the context, but that is "veamos" right? In fact, in the English version, it's "Now let's look at"

If anybody wants to hear what I'm talking about, send me an email, and I'll send you an audio file; it's 3,540 KB (9 minutes). The word in question is in the last minute or probably less.

If interested, email me at b clay shannon (one word) at att dot net

Alternatively (I'll be away from my computer for most of the day today), you can download chapter 37 from the "audio" link [here](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/?contentLanguageFilter=es&pubFilter=lr&sortBy=1)

Comment: You probably heard `fíjemonos`, which comes from the verb `fijar` - `fijarse`, look at something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `Fijémonos`

Comes from the verb `fijarse`

It like saying,

> Let's now focus on ... [something else]